# Move onto the next cell if operation takes too long Google Scripts

Tags: javascript, gwt, google-sheets

Looking for help on a google spreadsheet script that is used for scraping. The issue I am running into is that some times it takes the function too long to pull up the result. I would like to put in place a sort of 'move to the next cell' if it does not return anything within 5 seconds.

```
function bulkXml() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var Num = Browser.inputBox("How many URLs do you need to scrape?");

    for (x=2; x-2 < Num; x++)  {
        var url = sheet.getRange(x,1).getValue();
        sheet.getRange(2,6).setValue(url);
        var xpathResult = sheet.getRange(3,6).getValue();    
        var counter = x - 1;
        sheet.getRange("C4").setValue(counter + "/" + Num);
        sheet.getRange(x,2).setValue(xpathResult);
    }
}
```

Example of the output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could add a timeout in the beginning of your loop.
This will schedule the processing to be skipped if nothing changes in 5 seconds.

I have created this sample code which resembles your problem.

```
// Dictionary to keep track of the status of each cell
var skipCells = {};

function skipCellTester() {
    for (var x = 1; x <= 3; x++) {
        // Schedule this index to be skipped in 5 seconds.
        scheduleSkipCell(x, 5);

        console.log("Processing cell " + x);

        /*
         Set the cell status to true if you don't want to skip it anymore.
         Here I am saying that cell 2 should not be skipped.
         */
        if (x == 2)
            skipCells[x] = true;
    }
}

function scheduleSkipCell(x, seconds) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (!skipCells[x])
            console.log("Skipping cell " + x);
        else
            console.log("Do not skip cell " + x);
    }, seconds * 1000);

}

skipCellTester();
```